# Gsonを使ったjsonのパースがうまくいかない

Tags: java, json

以下のコードを使って以下のjsonから値を取得しようとしています．

```json
{
"block_size":50,
"mosaic_size_h":45,
"mosaic_size_w":80,
"0":"0",
"1":"3",
"2":"3",
"3":"3",
"4":"3",
...
}
```

```java
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CreateMosaic {
    public void CreateMosaicArt(String pMosaic){
        int size=0;
        int w=0;
        int h=0;
        Log.d("json",pMosaic);

        JsonObject jsonObject=(JsonObject) new Gson().fromJson(pMosaic,JsonObject.class);

        size=jsonObject.getAsJsonObject().get("block_size").getAsInt();
        w=jsonObject.getAsJsonObject().get("mosaic_size_w").getAsInt();
        h=jsonObject.getAsJsonObject().get("mosaic_size_h").getAsInt();
        int imgNum[]=new int[w*h];
        for (int i=2;i<jsonObject.size();i++){
            imgNum[i]=jsonObject.getAsJsonObject().get(String.valueOf(i)).getAsInt();
        }
        Log.d("size",String.valueOf(size));
        Log.d("w",String.valueOf(w));
        Log.d("h",String.valueOf(h));
        Log.d("imgs", Arrays.toString(imgNum));

    }

}
```

しかし以下のようなエラーが出ます

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tadatouta.downloadtest, PID: 14807
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsInt()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.tadatouta.downloadtest.CreateMosaic.CreateMosaicArt(CreateMosaic.java:30)
        at com.example.tadatouta.downloadtest.MainActivity$1.CallBack(MainActivity.java:25)
        at com.example.tadatouta.downloadtest.DownloadTask.onPostExecute(DownloadTask.java:93)
        at com.example.tadatouta.downloadtest.DownloadTask.onPostExecute(DownloadTask.java:13)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Application terminated.
```

どうすれば正しく動きますか？

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (int i=2;i<jsonObject.size();i++){
        imgNum[i]=jsonObject.getAsJsonObject().get(String.valueOf(i)).getAsInt();
    }
```

の部分の、 `jsonObject.getAsJsonObject().get(String.valueOf(i))` の戻り値が`null`、つまり、 `String.valueOf(i)`を実行した結果と等しい[プロパティ名が存在しない](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html#get-java.lang.String-)、ということでしょう。

```
{
    "block_size":50,
    "mosaic_size_h":45,
    "mosaic_size_w":80,
    "0":"0",
    "1":"3",
    "2":"3",
    "3":"3",
    "4":"3"
}
```

でいうと、 `jsonObject.size()` は8なので `String.valueOf(i)` 実行結果は `"2"`, `"3"`, `"4"`, `"5"`, `"6"`, `"7"`を取りますが、このうち`"5"`, `"6"`, `"7"` のプロパティ名がありません。

---

正しく動作させる修正方法は、仕様がわからないので正確なところはわかりませんが、例えばこういう感じのループ条件に書き換えることでしょうか。

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.size() - 3; i++) {
```

Comment: 再現コード&問題解消例はこちらです: https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/jaso52956